# Is there any SonarCloud API that can retrieve historical trend of issue by severity?

Tags: sonarcloud

I am looking to retrieve SonarCloud historical trend data of `Vulnerabilities`, `Bugs` and `Security Hotspot` with Severity of `BLOCKER` and `CRITICAL` only.

I have used this API `https://sonarcloud.io/api/issues/search?componentKeys={project_key}&types=BUG,VULNERABILITY,SECURITY_HOTSPOT&severities=CRITICAL,BLOCKER` which only shows me latest issue with `BLOCKER` and `CRITICAL` severity.

I am more interested for a historical trend like this API `https://sonarcloud.io/api/measures/search_history?metrics=critical_violations&from=2020-01-01&ps=100&component={project_key}` but this violations include `CODE_SMELLS` which is something I do not want to track. If I swap the metrics for `Vulnerabilities`, `Bugs` and `Security Hotspot`, it wont shows severity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, according to one of the SonarSourcer response. There is no API that can search historical trend on issue by severity only.

Reference: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/is-there-an-api-to-retrieve-historical-trend-of-issue-by-certain-severity-only/31930